# How does the 6 DOF Positional tracking work with infrared lights and a camera?

Tags: opencv, computer-vision

I have read many articles about how the Oculus postional tracking system works,  how infrared lights are detected by camera as dots, and then these dots are connected to construct 3D model of the object, that is VR glasses. Finally we have 6 DOF positional tracking system.

Now, how a one can track the object's position in the space by this model? 
I studied some CV, is it 3D Pose Estimation?

Comment: I don't think this style of question is really suited for SO.

Comment: @AndySavage I had actually felt that my question is not in the right place. However, I already entered Computer Science section and I did not find a lot of tags about computer vision. Is there any place where I can post such question? I will delete the question here.